# How can I find out which methods are called in Javascript when debugging without knowing the methods beforehand?

Tags: javascript, debugging, events, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

For example, I want to debug a third party library. It has a plethora of functions within it and I have no idea where to start. Is there a quick way to find out which functions are being fired without prior knowledge of the code base and thus not knowing where to put the break points?

Comment: Not sure but sometimes profiler helps.

Comment: I once had the same situation and I was motivated enough to do it at any cost. So I built a utility in C# that went through each function in my javascript file and wrote console.log(nameOfCurrentFunction) on top of each function. And then I wrote a function which acted as a switch for all the console.log().

Comment: And now I am exited to realize how stupid I was to do that.

Comment: Why do you want to debug third-party code?

Comment: Why would I not want to?

Comment: Because third-party code is maintained by somebody else. It normally only makes sense to debug it if you then tell the author about it or provide a patch, so he/she can fix it there.

Answer (score 1):

To see which functions are called, you should use the JavaScript profiler of your favorite debugging tool.

Those profilers output information about what functions were called from where and how often (i.e. how costly they are).

**In Firebug (version 2.0):**

1. Enable the *Script* and the *Console* panel
2. Switch to the *Console* panel
3. Click the *Profile* button
4. Do some actions, which call functions within the third-party code.
5. Click the *Profile* button again

Result:
[image: Firebug profiler output]

**In Firefox DevTools:**

1. Switch to the *Performance* panel
2. Click the *Start Recording Performance* button
3. Do some actions, which call functions within the third-party code.
4. Click the *Stop Recording Performance* button
5. Switch to the *Call Tree* tab

Result:
[image: Firefox DevTools profiler output]

**In Chrome/Opera DevTools:**

1. Switch to the *Timeline* panel
2. Click the *Record* button (or press <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd>
3. Do some actions, which call functions within the third-party code.
4. Click the *Finish* button
5. Switch to the *Aggregated details* tab

[image: Chrome/Opera DevTools profiler output]

Answer (score 0):

Usually third parties have a variable or function they expose, for example jQuery, `$` or `window.whatever`.

The browser developer tools (doesn't matter whether that are the Firefox DevTools, Chrome DevTools, Web Inspector in Opera or Firebug) offer a way to create watch expressions within their JavaScript debugging tools. Depending on the tool you use the related panel is called *Watch Expressions*, *Watch* or *Variables*.

In there, add the variable you DO know, expand it and start your search from there.

Comment: Not practical at all.